# Trigonometry solving in python

Tags: python, trigonometry

The question is:
How do I verify that sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1 for =,/2,/4,/6?

I have no idea on how to approach this problem
Please Help!
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The [`math` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: I assume you already know that `sin^2(x) + cos(^2) == 1` for *all* values of `x` for which `sin` and `cos` are defined?

Comment: This can go in: math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, `^` in python is bitwise XOR. To raise x to the y power, you do `x ** y`. To do math operations like `sin` and `cos`, you would use the builtin `math` module. Lastly, to check if a value is equal to another value, you use `==`. So checking what you wrote out would look like this:

```py
import math

x = math.pi

print(math.sin(x) ** 2 + math.cos(x) ** 2 == 1)
```